# random quote machine with AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I want create a random quote machine with help of AJAX. I found this API here https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/

and I uses this example code (from the page above)

```
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
  $("body").append(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
});
```

But I became the following error message

> Failed to load http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I run a simple local web-server (python).

I tried it in two different browsers, Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome this allow-cross-origin problem in python, you can use **CORS** package. Refer [Flask-CORS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors).

http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback= 
The above link you used in your code will give response in JSON format. You cannot allow cross-origin in this format.

In your api's documentation page ([Quotes on Design](https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/)) itself they gave different url (http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback) to get around the cross-origin thing. Try using this url. (Read your url documentation once more)

But this url also will throw an error like **insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint** because of url is **http**(not secure).

If your use-case is to just show random quotes in your page. I will recommend you to use my code below.

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) { 
            var quote = data.quoteText;
            if(data.quoteAuthor != ""){
              var author = data.quoteAuthor;
            }
            else{
          var author = "Unknown";
        }
        $('body').append("<p>"+ quote + "</p><p>&mdash; " + author + "</p>");

    },
    error: function (data) {
        quote = "A year spent in artificial intelligence is enough to make one believe in God.";
        author = "Alan Perlis";
        $('body').append("<p>"+ quote + "</p><p>&mdash; " + author + "</p>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin can be tricky. I got the same error as you so I rewrote it and got it to work doing this:

**VanillaJS Method:**

```
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1");

xhr.send(data);
```

**jQuery AJAX Method:**

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
  "method": "GET",
  "dataType":'json'
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Just add `$("body").append(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>"` where console.log is if you want to put the content in the same place as your example.